# Движок для сайта

Tags: html5, css3

Всем привет! Вопрос такой. Нужен ли сайту движок или что-то типа ядра для его запуска на сервере? Нужен ли файл типа "Start.bat"? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нужен [веб-сервер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%E5%E1-%F1%E5%F0%E2%E5%F0) – процесс(ы), постоянно работающий и ждущий, когда же кто-нибудь заглянет и спросит «есть страница?».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это зависит от того, на чем написан сайт! Если сайт написан на "движке", то нужен сам код этого "движка" на сервере. Если сайт статический, то не нужен. А по поводу start.bat... зависит все от движка, на котором написан сайт (имя bootstarp файла). Могу только предположить, что Вы используете Windows и start.bat у Вас запускает web-сервер (возможно, у Вас denwer). Но на хостингах денвер или подобное не требуется, там свои веб-сервера.